# how to make a jdbc sampler execute only once in a thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want a jdbc sampler execute only once in a thread group in jmeter.

I tried using a once only controller and a if controller (${__threadNum} == 1)
but it doesn't seem to work. The jdbc sampler keeps repeating along with other samplers. what am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following condition (assumes [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) which has better performance than JavaScript)

```
${__jexl3(${__threadNum} == 1 && ${__jm__Validate Pin__idx} == 0 ,)}
```

If you change the name of the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you will need to change the condition to exactly match the name.

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)